# Enable to execute command " ionic cordova run android " in Windows 10

Tags: mongodb, angular, cordova, firebase, ionic-framework

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\wamp64\www\ionic\spetinfo\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 64
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project `'android'`.

  > No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version `19.1.0` or higher.
- Try:
  Run with `--stacktrace` option to get the stack trace. Run with `--info` or `--debug` option to get more log output.

> [ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova run android (exit code 1).

Comment: Install Adroid Studio?

Comment: Thanks for your comment vicatcu, i already installed android studio and set ANDROID_HOME also. But, no use with that.

Comment: From Android Studio SDK manager, install Android build tools

Comment: Have you updated the android sdk took as ur error message clearly saying that u have not installed build tools